# Selenium Finding hover button element by class name in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, classname

Happy Sunday,

Trying to click a filter button (called offer) on a [website](https://beta.freecycle.org/town/BathUK). It is a hover button that does not have an associated link so cannot find element by link text.

[When clicking Offer button, the wanted button goes from `class="item-list-header-filter-icon item-list-wanted-filter hover-state"` to `class="item-list-header-filter-icon item-list-wanted-filter hover-state inactive"`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLYHP.jpg)

I have tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name(item-list-header-filter-icon item-list-wanted-filter hover-state)
```

and since it is a dynamic, I made webdriver wait:

```
        try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "item-list-header-filter-icon item-list-wanted-filter hover-state inactive"))
        )
        element.click()
```

Any ideas much appreciated!
Have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform a hover over that element.
It can be done as following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

offer = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.item-list-header-filter-icon.item-list-offer-filter')
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(offer)
hover.perform()
```

In case all you asked for is to locate that element you can simply do it with

```
offer = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.item-list-header-filter-icon.item-list-offer-filter')
```